# Can I configure Spring Security to prompt for domain name, along with user name and password

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I am authenticating using LDAP, and everything works fine for users within a specific domain. But I'm having difficulty understanding how I can authenticate users that are under a second domain. My current configuration shown below specifies the first domain in the user-search-base. I removed that parameter, in hopes that it would search all domains, but that didn't work. I also tried specifying the domain as part of the user name when prompted, such as domain\user, but this didn't work either.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
         <security:ldap-authentication-provider 
          user-search-filter="(samaccountname={0})" 
          user-search-base="dc=domain,dc=company,dc=com"
          user-context-mapper-ref="userContextMapper" >
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server 
    url="ldap://some.url.com:3000" 
    manager-dn="CN=USER1,OU=FacMgr,OU=FAC,OU=Exchange,dc=domain,dc=company,dc=com" 
    manager-password="xxxx"/>
```

Will I need to create a custom search, and if so, can someone provide an example in this context?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're using Active Directory, in which case I wonder why you're not using the more basic ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class.

At any rate, you should be able to accomplish what you need by extending either LdapAuthenticationProvider or ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider, and passing the appropriate domain to the superclass' method.

Create a constructor which accepts two different LdapAuthenticator objects, and add a second 'try' statement in the `doAuthentication` method's `catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound)` statement (after the check against bad credentials). Use whatever approach you like to get the `getAuthenticator` method to try the second authenticator if the first one fails.

This approach should work, but if both domains have a username of `jsmith`, but the user in question resides on the second, you may encounter problems -- that is, this is not a particularly *good* solution, but it *is* a solution.

To build this all up properly, use a custom authentication filter (extend the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter), and have the `LdapAuthenticationProvider.getAuthenticator()` method identify the domain from the value passed by the filter (in your custom login form).

You may need different manager accounts, but this is hopefully enough for you to go on.

Comment: In case you haven't solved your issue yet, I happened across [this gem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/485524/Spring/SpEL) while looking for a way to inject a dynamic field into a SpEL expression. From the looks of things, you should be able to specify two different LDAP beans in your `ldap.xml` configuration file, and then reference the relevant bean based on the domain input (i.e. via a controller which intercepts the login request and forwards it dynamically) via annotation. Specifically, look for the comment which references lists a `TaxRuleProcessor` object. It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to making this work is to use ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. To do this, just make the following changes:

In resources.groovy:

```
// Domain 1
ldapAuthProvider1(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider,
        "mydomain.com",
        "ldap://mydomain.com/"
)

// Domain 2
ldapAuthProvider2(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider,
        "mydomain2.com",
        "ldap://mydomain2.com/"
)
```

In Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider1', 'ldapAuthProvider2']
```

This is all the code you need. You can pretty much remove all other grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.* settings in Config.groovy as they don't apply to this AD setup.

Documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-active-directory